# Different Forms of Complex Chain Rule

Tags: complex-analysis

In Complex Variables by Joseph Taylor two forms of the chain rule are presented. First, as a theorem:

If $g$ is (complex) differentiable at $a$ and f is (complex) differentiable at $b=g(a)$, then

$$(f \circ g)'(a)=f'(g(a))g'(a)$$

Later, in a section of exercises, the reader is asked to prove the following (and given the hint that the proof is very similar to the proof of the above theorem):

If $g$ is analytic on an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{C}$ and $\gamma : [a,b] \rightarrow U$ is a path in U, then

$$(g \circ \gamma)'(t) = g'( \gamma (t)) \gamma'(t)$$

Why is the second form not simply a direct consequence of the first? What further work is required to prove the second form? My current thought is that the path may not be smooth. I.e we need to deal with the points in $[a,b]$ where the left hand and right hand derivative of $\gamma$ may not agree.

Comment: In the first theorem, both functions $f$ and $g$ are supposed to be complex differentiable maps $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ (possibly defined on a smaller open $U \subset \mathbb C$). However, a path $\gamma: [a,b] \to U$ is not such a map, so doesn't make sense to consider the complex derivative. If the path $\gamma$ is real differentiable, then $\gamma'(t)$ is a vector in $\mathbb R^2$ and you may consider this vector as a complex number.

Comment: This is covered by my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2872507. Note, however, that $\gamma$ must be differentiable at $t$ in order that your formula makes sense.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the link!